# CSS transition transform

Tags: html, css, transform, transition

I would like to ask if there's a way to only rotate the icon when the mouse is over the whole text?

Code looks like this:

```css
.text .icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 40px;
  
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.icon:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">
  <span class="icon">i</span><a href="#" target="_blank">Text</a>
</p>
```

The icons spins, but only with mouse over itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `.text:hover .icon` as the selector and it will rotate when hovering over the p element.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that an element with `display: inline` should not be a [transformable element](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transformable-element), and thus the `transform` property won't apply to it. To make it work, you can add

```css
.text > .icon {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And then, to set some style to `.icon` when `.text` is hovered, you should use this selector:

```css
.text:hover > .icon
```

```css
.text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.text > .icon {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text:hover > .icon {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

```html
<p class="text">
  <span class="icon">i</span><a href="#" target="_blank">Text</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Sami answered first because of the annoying captcha :(

Comment: Yes, but yours is more complete...have 10. :)